# Python Command Line Argument sys.argv not working

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm having some trouble using sys.argv in order to be able to run the program from the command line. I am running IDLE 3.5. I have tried running the program below both through a command prompt and the Python(3.5) command line. On both I am receiving an error:

in Python(3.5):

```
>>> python testing.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python testing.py
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

in Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\Brice_000>python testing.py
python: can't open file 'testing.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

testing.py reads:

```
import sys

def main():
    print sys.argv


if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv)
```

The tutorial I watched shows that this python file, when executed from the command line will return just the name of the program "testing.py"

I have a suspicion that somehow there's an issue with the file directories and when the command line is trying to open the file, it isn't there.

Does anyone know how I might go about figuring out what the issue is? And if so, how can I correct it?

Sorry if my question here is poorly formed. I'm new to python and stackoverflow and I don't really know what I'm doing yet.

Output of dir:

```
C:\Users\Brice_000>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 60E5-73E9

 Directory of C:\Users\Brice_000

11/01/2015  04:45 PM    <DIR>          .
11/01/2015  04:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/01/2015  04:47 PM    <DIR>          .gimp-2.8
11/01/2015  05:07 PM    <DIR>          .idlerc
06/21/2015  09:20 PM    <DIR>          .jagex_cache_32
08/23/2015  08:00 PM    <DIR>          .oracle_jre_usage
01/11/2013  03:59 PM    <DIR>          .swt
11/01/2015  04:45 PM    <DIR>          .thumbnails
09/15/2015  10:12 PM    <DIR>          3D Objects
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Contacts
08/29/2015  04:28 PM    <DIR>          Creative Cloud Files
11/16/2015  05:08 PM    <DIR>          Desktop
11/20/2015  11:32 PM    <DIR>          Documents
11/24/2015  02:26 PM    <DIR>          Downloads
04/08/2013  10:26 PM    <DIR>          Dropbox
01/12/2013  01:16 PM    <DIR>          dumps
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Favorites
06/21/2015  09:37 PM                23 jagexappletviewer.preferences
02/26/2013  06:31 PM    <DIR>          jagexcache
06/21/2015  09:21 PM    <DIR>          jagexcache1
02/19/2013  07:45 PM                50 jagex_cl_loginapplet_LIVE.dat
05/13/2014  10:34 PM                48 jagex_cl_oldschool_LIVE.dat
06/21/2015  09:21 PM                48 jagex_cl_runescape_LIVE.dat
06/21/2015  09:21 PM                49 jagex_cl_runescape_LIVE1.dat
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Links
10/20/2015  05:30 AM    <DIR>          Music
11/05/2015  12:42 AM    <DIR>          OneDrive
10/28/2015  08:50 PM    <DIR>          Pictures
06/22/2015  12:32 AM                24 random.dat
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Saved Games
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Searches
08/04/2015  08:35 PM    <DIR>          SkyDrive
02/25/2014  03:54 AM    <DIR>          SkyDrive (2).old
04/07/2014  01:55 PM    <DIR>          SkyDrive (3).old
02/16/2014  02:50 PM    <DIR>          SkyDrive.old
03/12/2015  08:15 PM    <DIR>          Tracing
10/14/2015  08:48 AM    <DIR>          Videos
               6 File(s)            242 bytes
              31 Dir(s)  49,005,813,760 bytes free
```

Comment: You need to run `python filename.py` **on the command line**, not in the Python interpreter. Are you sure you're in the right directory when you try that?

Comment: I thought I was? I am using Python 3.5(command line - 32bit)

Comment: Not when you get `SyntaxError` you aren't!

Comment: when in `C:\Users\Brice_000>` show us the output of `dir` command

Comment: Okay then, I must be doing this wrong. How exactly would I access the command line? I'm on windows 10, IDLE 3.5

Comment: You just said in your question you were using the command prompt...

Comment: adding dir to main post

Comment: `cmd` is command prompt/terminal/command line, `idle` is interpreter/repl

Comment: So `testing.py` isn't in the directory - how is Python supposed to find it? You need to **c**hange **d**irectory to the appropriate location.

Comment: I used both the command prompt and what I thought was the command line

Comment: okay, how do I add it to the directory?

Comment: Seriously? That's basic computer operation - if you can't manage that, you're a ways from programming.

Comment: Come on man... I'm trying :/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're running from a python interpreter.

You need to run this on the command line (Terminal on OS X, Command Prompt? on Windows).

```
# terminal or command prompt!
python testing.py
```

This means that you tell Python to execute the testing.py script.

Comment: Wobba Wob!

I am using Python 3.5(command line - 32bit), is this incorrect?

Comment: You're in what's called a Python shell. This means that Python will evaluate each command that you provide, as opposed to a shell, which delegates the script to run to python. Are you in IDLE?

Comment: IDLE provides a python, interactive interpreter. You're already running python, so there's no point trying to run it again, especially since it won't recognize it. Go to Command Prompt, switch to the directory of the file, and call `python testing.py`, and its should run.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't actually understand what I'm editing and what I'm editing it to.

Comment: @BricePetty What's the directory that `testing.py` is located? Copy that, and open up Command Prompt, and type `cd 'your directory'`, and on the next line, type `python testing.py`.

Comment: C:\Users\Brice_000>Python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help
Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
>>> cd C:\Python 3.5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd C:\Python 3.5
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Why are you typing `Python` first? Don't. Just type the two things that I told you to.

Comment: >>> cd C:\Users\Brice_000\test.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd C:\Users\Brice_000\test.py
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Alright. Type `cd C:\Users\Brice_000` in command prompt. ***Don't Type PYTHON!***. *Then*, type `python testing.py`

Comment: Umm.... Do the same thing, but type `python test.py`. From your question, I thought the file was called `testing.py` -_- |

Comment: got it to work. thank you very much. I'm sorry I'm difficult :[